# Hostname constraint in Symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to build a form in Symfony. The length constraint works but the hostname is not. If the tld and domain name are wrong, I got the custom error message I wrote. But if the tld and domain are good (I tried one my functional mail addresses) I still get the error message.
The problem so far is that even if the domain and tld I use are correct, Symfony throws me the error message corresponding to an invalid domain. I have no need to restrict specific domain.
Thanks for your time

(If it can be of any use, the project is here : https://github.com/Yamazaki-Ryuji/charles-letang)

My ContactTypeController

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\EmailValidation;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\NoRFCWarningsValidation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Hostname;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedValueException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\LogicException;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator as EguliasEmailValidator;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator as StrictEmailValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;



class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fullName',TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Votre nom'], 
                'constraints' => new Length(['min' =>'2', 'max' => '35'])
            ])
            ->add('email',EmailType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Votre email'], 
                'constraints' => new Hostname()
            ])
            ->add('subject',TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Sujet']
            ])
            ->add('message', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => false, 
                'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Votre message']
            ])
            ->add('check', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'En cochant cette case, vous acceptez la politique de confidentialité.' 
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // Configure your form options here
        ]);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target({"PROPERTY", "METHOD", "ANNOTATION"})
 *
 * @author Dmitrii Poddubnyi <dpoddubny@gmail.com>
 */
#[\Attribute(\Attribute::TARGET_PROPERTY | \Attribute::TARGET_METHOD | \Attribute::IS_REPEATABLE)]
class Hostname extends Constraint
{
    public const INVALID_HOSTNAME_ERROR = '7057ffdb-0af4-4f7e-bd5e-e9acfa6d7a2d';

    protected static $errorNames = [
        self::INVALID_HOSTNAME_ERROR => 'INVALID_HOSTNAME_ERROR',
    ];

    public $message = 'Adresse email invalide.';
    public $requireTld = true;

    public function __construct(
        array $options = null,
        string $message = null,
        bool $requireTld = null,
        array $groups = null,
        $payload = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($options, $groups, $payload);

        $this->message = $message ?? $this->message;
        $this->requireTld = $requireTld ?? $this->requireTld;
    }
}
```

The index.html.twig file

```php
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Contact{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    <div class="contact-page">
        <div class="contact-form">
            <p>Je suis intéressé par les projets freelance tout autant que pour un contrat.<br>
                Si vous avez une question ou besoin d'un renseignement,<br> 
                n'hésitez pas à m'envoyer un message</p>
                <div class="contact-fields">
                    <div class="form-group name" title="Saisissez votre nom">
                        {{ form_start(our_form) }}
                        {{ form_row(our_form.fullName, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control-name-field', 
                        'type': 'name', 'data-min': '2', 'data-max': '255',
                        'oninvalid': "setCustomValidity('Veuillez saisir votre nom')", 
                        'oninput': "setCustomValidity('')"}}) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mail" title="Saisissez votre e-mail">
                        {{ form_row(our_form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control-mail-field', 
                        'type': 'email',
                        'oninvalid': "setCustomValidity('Veuillez saisir une adresse email')", 
                        'oninput': "setCustomValidity('')"}}) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group subject" title="Saisissez le sujet de votre message">
                        {{ form_row(our_form.subject, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control-subject-field', 
                        'oninvalid': "setCustomValidity('Veuillez saisir un sujet')", 
                        'oninput': "setCustomValidity('')"}}) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group message" title="Saisissez votre message">
                        {{ form_row(our_form.message, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control-message-field', 
                        'oninvalid': "setCustomValidity('Veuillez saisir un message')", 
                        'oninput': "setCustomValidity('')"}}) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="rgpd" title="Politique de confidentialité">
                        {# <a><label type="checkbox" class="js-verif-rgpd" required="required"></a>
                        En cochant cette case, j'accepte la <a class="confidentiality" href="{{ path('privacy') }}">politique de confidentialité</a> #}
                        {{ form_row(our_form.check, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control-check-field', 
                        'oninvalid': "setCustomValidity('Veuillez accepter la politique de confidentialité')", 
                        'oninput': "setCustomValidity('')"}}) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="form-group submit">
                        <a><button type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="submit-button">Envoyer</button></a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    {{ form_end(our_form) }}
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
            {# <div class="mentions">
                <h1 class="mentions-title">Mentions légales</h1>
                    <p>
                        SIRET : 912 175 015 000 11<br>
                        Hébergeur : OVH
                    </p>
            </div> #}
{% endblock %}
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA0Db.jpg)

Comment: That's your `Constraint` class, where is your `ConstraintValidator`? I _think_ that since there is a `Hostname` constraint it's calling its default `HostnameValidator`, and an email it's not a valid host. Also, I don't think the initialization of the `requireTld` makes much sense: what are you coalescing to? If you pass the value in `$options` it would be set (through the `parent::__construct`, but otherwise it'll still be `null`. And I'm assuming there is a reason to not use [the built-in `Email` constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html)?

Comment: Actually I do have a Hostname Validator. If I understood correctly, I used Hostname instead of Email to prevent Symfony to send an email with a domain name without the .fr ou .com.
Also, I'm not using an entity as suggested in the link you provided.
P.S: I'm still new to Symfony as you could guess

Comment: You can still use the constraint in a form without the need for an entity, just like you did with `Length`. An email without a tld woud not pass validation, would it? So it should be safe to use, just be sure to send the email only if the form is valid. Unless what you want is to restrict the possible destination domains. Could you [edit] the question and explain? And add the `Validator` as well if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @msg. I've edited my question, I hope this is a bit clearer. 
The validator you're mentioning is HostnameValidator.php right?

Comment: I was, but after looking at the constraint once again I noticed the namespace, and looks like the built-in. And sorry, but I still don't understand what "something.com is good" means. That it is syntactically valid (contains a domain name and tld)? That the tld is valid? That the hostname itself exists? That it is "allowed" in some sense? Otherwise, what you seem to need is the `Email` constraint (probably in `strict mode`).

Comment: I actually am using the built in and it's working properly for the Length value. I'd like to be sure that the tld is valid before sending the email (to avoid .f or .come). If I use the Email constraint, Symfony tries to send the email (even if the tld isn't valid). If I use the Hostname constraint, Symfony doesn't send the email even if the tld is valid. I hope it's a bit clearer now. Thanks again for your time